# Having some issues with a JavaScript classes exercise

Tags: javascript, module, es6-class

im currently doing a JavaScript exersise involving classes and just cant seem to get it working, even when i follow the example exactly. anyu help and exlinations would be greatly appretiated, thanks
here is the exersise so you can see the end goal and what ive been following:
https://gamr1520.github.io/GAMR1520/exercises/6.2.html

code bellow (forgot to add moduleScript.js, added it now):

Modules.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>classes and modules</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="moduleScript.js" type="module" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classes and Moduels</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="150"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

thing.js

```
export default class Thing {
    constructor(x, y, size, hue) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.fillStyle = `hsl(${hue}, 30%, 60%)`;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.rotationRate = 0;
        this.speed = 100;
    }
    
    get xSpeed() {
        return Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speed;
    }
    get ySpeed() {
        return Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speed;
    }

    update(elapsed) {
        this.rotattionRate += (Math.random() - 0.5);
        this.rotationRate = Math.max(this.rotationRate, -2 * Math.PI);
        this.rotationRate = Math.min(this.rotationRate, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.angle += this.rotationRate * elapsed;
        this.x += this.xSpeed * elapsed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed * elapsed;
    }

    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, this.size/2, Math.PI / 2, 1.5 * Math.PI)
        ctx.lineTo(this.size, 0);
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

follower.js

```
export default class Follower {
    constructor(x, y, speed, target) {
        this.target = target;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    get angle() {
        const dy = this.target.y - this.y;
        const dx = this.target.x - this.x;
        return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    }

    get xSpeed() {
        return Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speed;
    }

    get ySpeed() {
        return Math.sin(this.angle) * this.spped;
    }

    update(elapsed) {
        this.x += this.xSpeed * elapsed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed * elapsed;
    }

    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.target.fillStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-10, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(10, 0);
        ctx.moveTo(5, -5);
        ctx.lineTo(10, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(5, 5);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

scene.js

```
import Thing from './thing.js';
import Follower from './follower.js';

export default class Scene {
    constructor(nThings, canvas) {
        this.things = Array.from({length: nThings}, () => {
            return new Thing(

                Math.random() * canvas.width,
                Math.random() * canvas.height,
                20 + Math.random() * 10,
                Math.random() * 360, 
                Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI
            );
        });
        this.followes = this.things.map((thing) => {
            return new Follower(
                canvas.width / 2,
                canvas.height / 2,
                thing.speed / 2, thing
            );
        });
    }
    
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas,height);
        this.followers.forEach(thing => {
            thing.draw(ctx);
        });
        this.things.forEach(things => {
            thing.draw(ctx);
        });
    }

        update (elapsed) {
        this.things.forEach(thing => {
            thing.update(elapsed);
        });
        this.followers.forEach(thing => {
            thing.update(elapsed);
        });
    }
}
```

moduleScript.js

```
import Scene from './scene.js';

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const scene = new Scene(100, canvas);

let p;
function frame(ts) {
    const elapsed = ts - p || 0;
    scene.update(elapsed / 1000);
    scene.draw(ctx);
    p = ts;
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
} 
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

stylesheet.css

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #d6d6d6;
    font-family: monospace;
    max-width: auto;
}
canvas {
    background: #a1a1a1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention what the problem is. Also, where's "moduleScript.js"?

Comment: `this.angle = angle;` what is `angle`? `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas,height);` what is `height` - was the last `,` supposed to be a `.`? `this.things.forEach(things => { thing.draw(ctx);});` ... `things` vs `thing` - amazing what a code linter can find - two typos and an undeclared variable

Comment: @JaromandaX
thank you, i think i fixed the angle but im not sure how to fix the height

Comment: `ctx.canvas,height` isn't it obvious? look at `ctx.canvas.width` ... besides the last word ... what is difference?

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh i know about the comma instead of the full stop, i fixed that, I'm just not sure what else to do with height, you asked what is height so i assumed you mean it hasn't been defined like angle

Comment: because `ctx.canvas,height` is two tings ... `ctx.canvas` and `height` but `ctx.canvas.height` is one ting - dats why I said was the last `,` supose to be a `.`

Comment: *"cant seem to get it working"*: it is expected that you explain what the desired output is, what exactly goes wrong, what you have done to debug, and what results you have from debugging.